# How to align table to middle of the page, not just the text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I know this question has probably been asked million times. I've tried all the solutions I've found, but couldn't get what I need. I need to align the `<table>` to the middle of the page and remove the grid lines.

My code:

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<tr><td><img src="disc_uni.png" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="how_to_apply.png" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="stud_sup.png" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: i tried..its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
.table {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Try adding the above CSS and see if it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the end `</table>` tag is missing. this code should work for you:

```css
.container .table {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <tr><td><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I see the images are centered. What is the issue?

Comment: i tried removing grid lines ,but still left aligned.

Comment: <div class="container">
<table class="table borderless">

<tbody>
<tr><td>aaaaaaa</td></tr>
<tr><td>bbbbbbb</td></tr>
<tr><td>ccccccc</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>        css----
.container .table .borderless {
    margin:0 auto;
}

.borderless tbody tr td, .borderless tbody tr th, .borderless thead tr th {
    border: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

i updated my answer with jsfiddle for you to see it working  http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/ekjfzL4r/

```
     <div class="container">
           <center>
              <div class="newly_div">    
              <table class="table">
              <tr><td><img src="disc_uni.png" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
              <tr><td><img src="how_to_apply.png" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>
              <tr><td><img src="stud_sup.png" class="img-responsive" ></td></tr>                                               
              </div>
          </center>                    
    </div>
```

please pay attention i added another div  with class newly_div  the jsfiddle shows it is working thanks!

Comment: w8 il create an jsfiddle for you

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution by myself..
The problem was caused by the img-responsive class,when i remove the img-responsive class its working fine for whatever method we use to center the table.

But with the img-responsive class included ,below code worked for me.Thanks to everyone who responded.

### css

```
.table.borderless{
  table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;


}

.table.borderless tbody tr td{
    border: none;
text-align: center;
}

.img{
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

### HTML

```
<table class="table borderless">
<tr>
<td><img src="disc_uni.png" class="img-responsive img" ></td><td style="text-align:justify" ><br></br></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><img src="how_to_apply.png" class="img-responsive img" ></td><td>university</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="stud_sup.png" class="img-responsive img" ></td><td>university</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What on earth is in `.img-responsive` to require all that mess?! I realise that you've solved your question but for future reference, please edit in the CSS for `.img-responsive` (or add a non-stagnating link to the code) in your question.